# Compare two columns and export unique values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Ok, I have a master list of customer names on sheet 3, column c. On sheet 1, column c,  I type the names of the customers I have contacted. I want sheet 2, column c, to show a list of the names of customers that I haven't contacted yet. And I need it to update each time I type a name into sheet 1 that matches a name on sheet three.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Populate Sheet2 C1 and down with the following formula:
`=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(Sheet3!C1,Sheet1!C$1:C$10,1,0)=Sheet3!C1,""),Sheet3!C1)`.
As with user3654439's answer, which is good BTW, this will create a column that includes blanks which can be filtered out if desired. There is no need to make a table nor sort the data to get the formula to work. Also in the part of the formula `Sheet1!C$1:C$10` the `10`could be changed to match the length of the list of customers that you intend to contact.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is with is to create a table on each sheet, sort it, then use IF, ISERROR and MATCH function to show duplicates. [Here](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2013/09/05/compare-two-columns-remove-duplicates/) is a tutorial.

HTH,

M